# Radio Button in header

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have a header with several radio buttons that let the user choose between different list views. I am not able to change it so it goes in one line. The width of the four buttons is greater than the screen size and I am not able to limit the width of each input.

Here is the code of that part:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" style="height:45px;width:100%;">
<div class="centerFieldset">

    <fieldset class="radioBtn" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="margin-top:1px;">
        <label for="flow" >Rivers</label> 
        <input class="type" type="radio" name="radio" id="flow" value="flow"
            onClick="javascript:changeFlow()" <?php print $flow_selected;?> />
        <label for="lake" >Lakes</label> 
        <input class="type" type="radio" name="radio" id="lake" value="lake"
            onClick="javascript:changeLakes()" <?php print $lake_selected;?> />
        <label for="meteo" >Meteo</label>
        <input class="type" type="radio" name="radio" id="meteo" value="meteo"
            onClick="javascript:changeMeteo()" <?php print $meteo_selected;?>/>
        <label for="tableau" >Tableau</label>
        <input class="type" type="radio" name="radio" id="tableau" value="tableau"
            onClick="javascript:changeMeteo()" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS file is:

.centerFieldset {
    text-align: center;
}

.centerFieldset fieldset {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:100%;
}

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

When I try to limit the label width to 20% I get this:

[image]

Comment: what is exactly your question/problem?

Comment: I want the header to stay in one line! :-)

Comment: well, reduce the padding and margins of the `<label>` elements, e.g.? If nothing is specified yet, try to set them to a very low value...

Comment: I have tried. And I can when I put something like: width:72px; so when the screen changes size I have the same problem! If I put width:20%; I get very small buttons but they are still in place. I upload a photo so you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this layout is you are using radio button on the header... I think two or more css are included into the jquery generated divs in your radio button... Either use navbar for it or implement custom css for disabling the second css classes which are included in your radio buttons...

Comment: I will give it a try right now I I'll let you know if it works!! Thanks!

Comment: Navbars manages directly the screen width!! Worked perfectly! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

.centerFieldset { text-align: center; display:block; float:left }

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one

.centerFieldset { text-align: center; display:block; float:left }}

.centerFieldset fieldset { width:100% }

It should works